# Setting 'visibility: visible' is not working

Tags: jquery, css

Why is my `$('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');` not working?

```js
$('#clickdiv').click(function() {
    alert($('#myDiv').css('visibility'));
    if ($('#myDiv').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }

    if ($('#myDiv').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
        $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">hide/show</div>
<div id="clickdiv">click me</div>
```

Comment: i gess instead of using css function and setting visibility property, you need to use show()/hide() methods of jquery or simply use toggle method.  $('#myDiv').toggle();

Comment: @ijaz, no, show/hide sets the css display property. visiblity is a different property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You have two separate `if` conditions. The second will *always* fire when showing the div again. You need to combine to an `if`/`else` statement:

```
$('#clickdiv').click(function () {
    alert($('#myDiv').css('visibility'));
    if ($('#myDiv').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
    else {
        $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Note that you can improve the logic too using a ternary:

```
$('#clickdiv').click(function () {
    $('#myDiv').css('visibility', function(i, v) {
        return v == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6f48yx/3/)

You could even make it shorter by using `toggle()`, although that sets the `display` property not `visibility`, so may not meet your needs exactly.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan I didn't get the point why second `if` always fire. should  not in fire be on condition `true` or `false`

Comment: It's because the first `if` may set the property to `visible`. The second `if` then executes, finds that the value is `visible` and immediately changes it back to `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
$('#clickdiv').click(function(){
    alert($('#myDiv').css('visibility'));

    var visiblity = $('#myDiv').css('visibility');
    $('#myDiv')
       .css('visibility', visiblity == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6f48yx/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `is(':visible')` to check visibility of div

```
$('#clickdiv').click(function () {

        if ($('#myDiv').is(':visible')) {
            $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        else {
            $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second `if` to `else if`!

```
$('#clickdiv').click(function(){
    alert($('#myDiv').css('visibility'));
    if($('#myDiv').css('visibility') == 'hidden'){
       $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
    else if($('#myDiv').css('visibility') == 'visible'){
        $('#myDiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: Or just "else". No need for a second test.